# Change Konqueror format to single column

Tags: konqueror

I'm running Konqueror in Kubuntu 21.10. Is there a way to persuade it to do listings in a single column rather than three columns?

Update 1:   Konqueror is not the only Ubuntu program with this behavior, so a general solution would be very useful.  The three-column format  defies easy scrolling through a long list. To see the third column, you need to scroll horizontally, which is awkward and unnatural. It also makes list selection nearly impossible.

[image: Three-column listing]

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what you would like to change? I’m not sure which view (or layout) you might want to alter 

Comment: Please see the revised description of the problem.

Comment: I hope this screenshot is sufficient.